# Is there a difference between a Pokemon being nicknamed when caught vs the Name Rater?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

If I looked into the game's code and/or a save game, is it possible to tell the difference between a Pokemon renamed using the Name Rater, and a Pokemon named right after catching it?

It may seem silly, but it's really important to me that everything under the hood be the same. If there is a difference I'll probably avoid naming my Pokemon one way over the other.

I'd rather know now, then find out later and have to restart my save.

Comment: I have no evidence, this may require a data miner, but as a programmer I will assume that a Pokemon's nickname is stored in the same memory area, no matter when it's modified. It wouldn't have any sense to use 2 different "slots" to store the same information, since the game does not show any difference about the moment the Pokemon was named.

Answer (score 3):

The first generation of Pokemon games don’t store any metadata about how the nickname was applied, there is simply a 10 character field containing the nickname. If the nickname is not exactly equal to the species name, the Pokémon is considered nicknamed.

So you can nickname your Pokémon at the name rater and you will end up with the same result as if you’d nicknamed it straight away.

The data structures of Gen I are quite well known at this point. You can even look them up [on Bulbapedia](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Save_data_structure_(Generation_I)).